# Is the conio.h header file supported by gcc?

Tags: c, getch, conio

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main() {
    printf("hello world");
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using gcc 13.1, and I've read in an article that gcc doesn't support the `conio.h` file, but the above code is working fine without any errors or warnings.

Does GCC support `<conio.h>`?

Comment: May be platform dependent. Doesn't work here: https://godbolt.org/z/Kfxf34G1G Are you using MinGW on Windows?

Comment: Yes, seems to work on MinGW. Your source seems to be wrong. It would be better to say that `conio.h` only exists on Windows.

Comment: There exists no situation where you should be using conio.h anyway, unless you fancy a future career as MS DOS programmer...

Comment: @Lundin I do miss `kbhit` sometimes, but it's mostly a nostalgia thing.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Windows 95 kind of killed that one... grr. Everyone knows that threads belong in a sweater and not in an OS! What's next, removing the [Turbo button](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_button)?